# Search Bar - Cancel Button in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, button, searchbar

I'm doing Search Bar in Navigation Bar. When I'm editing I don't have Cancel Button on right side of navigation Bar.

Tried:

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    var barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "")
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT:

I added search bar to nav bar like this:

```
lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 20))

        searchBar.placeholder = "Hľadať"
        searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.BlackTranslucent
        var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView:searchBar)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cancel button is sort of a default option, since there's and option in UISearchBar that explicitly defines the "showsCancelButton", so I don't know that you need to be placing your own cancel button there.

Comment: I added searchbar programatically because I want it in Navigation Bar

Comment: I see, let me flesh out the other option for you then

Comment: @patffo Trying to set the `showsCancelButton` of the searchBar to `true`.

Comment: You can do this, but then the Cancel button is always shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in this way:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    var cancelSearchBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelBarButtonItemClicked")
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(cancelSearchBarButtonItem, animated: true)
    return true
}
```

And in the "Cancel" handler:

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // closes the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // If you are using a search controller
    // self.searchDisplayControllerCustom.setActive(false, animated: true)

    // remove the cancel button
    self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem(nil, animated: true)
}

func cancelBarButtonItemClicked() {
    self.searchBarCancelButtonClicked(self.searchBar)
}
```

And set the correct color for the navigation bar title text:

```
// This sets the textcolor for all navigation bars in the app
// Do this in the app delegate on startup
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

And add the delegate:

```
searchBar.delegate = self
```

Comment: Please make the text "Cancel" bigger, like "Cancel AAAAAAA" to check if the gap on the right gets bigger. It could be that just the wrong color is set.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the color. How have you set the search bar into the navigation bar?

Comment: Try to set the search bar in the center: self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

Comment: Is searchBarShouldBeginEditing really called? Have you set up the delegates? Please debug.

Comment: Well, then: searchBar.delegate = self

Comment: great! btw. Do you know how can I put placeholder to the left side?

Comment: What kind of placeholder?

Comment: in searchbar.. Btw.. When I press Cancel gives me error " unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15750dd60'"

Comment: searchBar.placeholder = "text"

Comment: Take care to add a double point at the selector. cancelBarButtonItemClicked:

Comment: Yeah I know that. But i mean alignment.. Because now I have it in middle..  I want in in the left side.

Comment: No, you cant change that.

Comment: Oh. Okey. And with that action: cancelBarButtonItemClicked? It's not working. Getting error. check my comment up here.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added the missing func cancelBarButtonItemClicked(). In this case the double point at the end of the selector is not needed, because cancelBarButtonItemClicked takes no parameters.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

If this is Objective-C answer:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
}
```

Then this might be the Swift answer: *(not 100% sure)*

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
}
```

Remember to link your delegate with self.

Source: [UISearchBar Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISearchBar/setShowsCancelButton)